# Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 - Provider can not be found or it may not be installed

Tags: vba, excel, oledb, jet

I have created an Excel Macro in which I have used Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 to fire query on Excel work sheets.

It's working perfect on my machine but my client is facing issue with it. (see the attached screen print)

[image: Client is getting this error]

[image: References I have added in the program]

Here are details for my Connection Object:

```
Dim cn
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
    .Open
End With
```

Please Note: It is must for me to make the code working in "Windows 7"

Comment: Anybody please make the images working. I have attached 2 images but it's not getting displayed here.

Comment: is your machine 32bit and the client machine 64bit? what is the os and the excel versions on your machine and your client machine?

Comment: Don't know about client's version. But I have tested that macro on both 32 & 64 bit windows 7 and it's working fine on both.

Comment: if the screen shot is from client. Then the theme looks like windows vista. unless we know the client os and the office version it is difficult to suggest you a solution. you need to ask your client for these information.

Comment: @Esen: I asked him and he told that he is using Windows 7. Observe the Task Bar. Height of task bar is not that big in Vista. So it's Win7 only I think. By Excel version what do u mean? 2010/2007 or do u mean 64 bit/32 bit?

Comment: If you had used early binding then you would see the missing reference in the References dialog

Comment: @esen : He has windows 7 and office 2010. And both are 64 bit. I confirmed again

Comment: @barrowc How can I achieve early binding? Can you please tell me?

Comment: Try this article - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The provider will fail like that on Window 7 Office x64 as the provider isn't supported on that platform.

You need to install the x64 [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255) and change your connection string to `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`

Comment: Thank you Alex. I will tell him to install the same & will send you the updated code.

Comment: My answer was poorly stated, it will fail on 64bit *office* but work on 32 bit office on x64 windows

Comment: hey it's still not working in client's PC. Can you please figure out what can be the reason?

Comment: I never would have thought in August 2021 I'd still be dealing with 32 bit software! This answer more so proved my hypothesis and I think fixed it but it's not my tool to fix at work. Thank you!