# Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 - Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed

Tags: vbscript

I recently started a new job and I am getting the error below when I run a script written by my predecessor. I do not get this error when I run the script on my predecessor's old laptop which is running 32 bit windows 7. I get it when I try to run the script on my desktop which is running 64 bit windows 7. I thought it might be an issue with compatibility between the 32 and 64 bit versions.

Error:
`Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.`

Code:

```
objConnection.Open  "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & FilePath & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;"";"
```

I found some other posts with the same error, but their fixes did not help me. This is the only one that had an accepted answer:
[Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 - Provider can not be found or it may not be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495232/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-can-not-be-found-or-it-may-not-be-installed)
I installed and changed the provider, but I got the same error.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using the 32 or 64-bit version of `cscript.exe/wscript.exe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a 32 bit issue then try 32 bit vbscript. `c:\windows\syswow64\wscript "c:\yourscript.vbs"`.

Comment: When I run it that way I get the error "File not found" on the line `Set oFile = oFS.OpenTextFile(inputFile)`. The input file does exist, and I do not get this error on the other machine.

Comment: You haven't posted that code. Also put in `msgbox inputfile` on the line above. Press Ctrl + C to copy message boxes to the clipboard.

Comment: Also `msgbox vartype(inputfile)`